# Hide empty option value with css

Tags: html, css

I have a select option html, i need to hide one of the options only with css without changing the html structure like adding more class or id.

here's the html structure:

```
<select id="net_terms_id" name="order[account][net_terms_id]" class="select admin__control-select">
       <option value>-Select Net Term-</option>
       <option value="Devtest">Devtest</option>
       <option value="15 Days Net">15 Days Net</option>
</select>
```

here's what i've done so far with the css:

```
#net_terms_id option:empty {display: none;}
#net_terms_id option[value=""] {display: none;}
```

Comment: I am afraid that it ain't possible. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option, but from my understanding the best you can do is disable it using JavaScript... the CSS won't apply as it is never actually rendered, but only read by select element.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the empty option with just css you can try adding `selected disabled hidden style='display: none'` and that should do the trick.

```html
<select id="net_terms_id" name="order[account][net_terms_id]" class="select admin__control-select">
       <option value selected disabled hidden style='display: none'>-Select Net Term-</option>
       <option value="Devtest">Devtest</option>
       <option value="15 Days Net">15 Days Net</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what you need

```html
<select>
  <option disabled selected>Choose..</option>
  <option>First option</option>
  <option>Second option</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have some doubts if it's real to do with css only. But maybe this helps
[this code hides first option in every selection set]:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("option")[0].style.display = "none";
```

OR hide first option with CSS as PraveenKumar said.

Answer (score -1):

You can hide the first option by using `:first-child`. But it will show as default.

```
#net_terms_id option:first-child {
   display:none;
}
```

You can do that by using jquery.

```js
$('#net_terms_id option').filter(function() {
  return !this.value || $.trim(this.value).length == 0 || $.trim(this.text).length == 0;
}).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="net_terms_id" name="order[account][net_terms_id]" class="select admin__control-select">
       <option value>-Select Net Term-</option>
       <option value="Devtest">Devtest</option>
       <option value="15 Days Net">15 Days Net</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
#net_terms_id option[value=empty]  {}
```